# Communicating between container docker Tor and Node

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, puppeteer

I'd like to use Tor with my NodeJs app, I made two Docker containers, one for my Node.js Puppeteer app and one for Tor.

The problem is that I can't use Tor as a proxy from my NodeJs application, i have this error :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error:
>   net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED at http://checkip.amazonaws.com/

When I try to communicate with my Tor container from my computer it work but not between the container.

**Here is my Tor Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN apk update
RUN apk add tor

RUN echo "Log notice stdout" >> /etc/torrc
RUN echo "ControlPort 9051" >> /etc/torrc
RUN echo "CookieAuthentication 0" >> /etc/torrc
RUN echo "SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9050" >> /etc/torrc

EXPOSE 9050

CMD tor -f /etc/torrc
```

> docker run -p 9050:9050 Tor

**Here's the code when I initialize the proxy with Puppeteer :**

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:9050',
      '--no-sandbox'
    ],
});
```

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

On my node app I changed the proxy by `'--proxy-server=socks5://tor:9050'`

I added `--link tor:tor` when I started my node container.